# Access permissions for selective files in a directory one level up

Tags: php, apache, security, permissions, restrictions

I have a website which has a lot of confidential data and code which I have custom made. I have hired a developer to do the designing and some simple PHP integration for me.

To prevent him from seeing all files, I made a test environment in one of subfolders like mywebsite.com/testfolder

Now I want him to access the db_test.php, function.php and parameter.php files which are located in the root folder such that he can just include them while executing the scripts (example mywebsite.com/testfolder/mainfile.php) and not download them (with php script or by any other means). The idea is to prevent him to see the code and just use the stuff as it is.

This would also mean that his access to the root folder should be also completely restricted except for the above mentioned files.

I have created a test database and a separate user for him so the database bit is secured.
I have also created a ftp user which can just access the testfolder through ftp

What I am concerned about is that he might run a php script that will give all secrets in the root folder.

I have myself been able to list and download files by running a simple php script from testfolder.

Please suggest how to make this work as I am planning to have a virtual team who will work on the website which will have restricted access to various different resources.

Answer (score 0):

**RULE NUMBER ONE**: never develop on a live project.

you may create a development environment (=web site) somewhere else, put some meaningless files and/or databases there and allow your developers full access. then, from time to time, you update your working copy from the repository (you have setup hg/git repo, haven't you), review and test the changes and only then upload files to your main web site.

Comment: That's one option. But if I do that, I would need to give them access to those files which I don't want to. I have made functions, parameters etc which I don't want anybody else to see and copy. The idea is that they can just include files and not do any operation on it.

Comment: don't use your real very secret files for development, create placeholders or specimens that contain meaningless data, or even don't use any files at all and provide the pre-canned answers through your API. the main point is -- don't develop on a live server, use separate server/machine with the fake data instead of real one.